# Rails is not rendering standard HAML layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm using HAML as my markup language. 
And my views render only self view, without layout application. If in my method I write

> render :layout => true

I'll get

> There was no default layout for HomesController in
>
> /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views]>

But if I rename application.html.haml to application.html.erb, all is ok. But scaffolds are generating HAML with no problem. What's wrong?

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
    #render :layout => 'application'
  end
end
```

view

```
%ul
  - @manufacturers.each do |manufacturer|
    %li      
      = link_to manufacturer.MFA_BRAND, vehiclemodel_url(:id => manufacturer.MFA_ID)
```

layout

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Title
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    - if current_user
      = "Signed in as #{current_user.email}. Not you?"
      = link_to "Sign out", logout_path
    - else
      = link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path
    %p
      Hello!
    %h4
      =yield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded solution:
in gemfile must be

> gem 'haml-rails'

so, gem haml is not need there, only haml-rails.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
gem 'haml'
```

to your Gemfile?

Comment: And you did run `bundle install` right after you changed the Gemfile? (Sorry if it's an obvious question, but I gotta check.)

Comment: In this case I'm afraid it's hard to say anything else without looking at your views and controllers.